# How do I iterate over Django CHOICES in a template - without using a form or model instance

Tags: python, django

I currently use choices to define a list of months and a list of days of the week.

I want to display these lists of choices in my templates without necessarily relating to a specific instance or form.

For instance...

In my models:

```
MONTH_CHOICES = (
    ('01', 'January'),
    ('02', 'February'),
    ('03', 'March'),
etc

DAY_CHOICES = (
    ('01', 'Monday'),
    ('02', 'Tuesday'),
    ('03', 'Wednesday'),
etc

class Item(models.Model):
    month = models.CharField(choices=MONTH_CHOICES)
    day = models.CharField(choices=DAY_CHOICES)
```

In my view:

```
month_choices = MONTH_CHOICES
```

In my template:

```
{% for month in month_choices %}
{{ month }}<br />
{% endfor %}
```

The above code outputs:

```
('01', 'January')
('02', 'February')
('03', 'March')
```

How do I output just the name (or value) of each choice?

Alternatively, is there a better way of recording a month and day of the week for a model - and later grouping/presenting instances using a month and a day?

THANKS! :)

Answer (score 22):

There's a better way to do this.

```
{% for value, text in form.[field_name].field.choices %}
    {{ value }}: {{ text }}
{% endfor %}
```

form is the form variable you pass to the template.
[field_name] is the field name you defined in your model. In this case 'month'

Answer (score 9):

You can simply unpack the tuple when iterating over it:

```
{% for n, month in month_choices %}
{{ n }}, {{ month }}<br />
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
{% for month in month_choices %}
{{ month.1 }}<br />
{% endfor %}
```

Although semantically you should probably use `<ul>` and `<li>` rather than `<br>`.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll give that a go...

I'm not actually using a <br> btw - I'm actually using the choices to arrange items in a table... with months forming one axis - and days forming another.

I'm not sure that using choices in the best way of doing this - but I can't find an easy way of constructing a Django field that truly represents months - and presents a list of months to the user

Comment: Any idea how I do the same thing in a view?  .1 doesn't seem to work...  I'm looping through the choices and it's outputting the whole tuple.