# Django shows names instead of objects

Tags: python, django

I have array of inputs

```
class ChooseColumnsForm(forms.Form):
    choices = (
        (1, ("")),
        (2, ("sn")),
        (3, ("cn")),
        (4, ("password")),
        (5, ("uid")),
        (4, ("mail"))
    )
    columns = []
    def set_columns(self, col):
        for i in range(0,col):
            self.columns.append(forms.ChoiceField(self.choices))
```

And i want to show them

```
{% for choice in columns %}
    <td>{{ choice }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

But instead of inputs I am getting names of that inputs.

[image: Output]

What i want to get

[image: Result]

I know i could just put the same input like thiu:

```
{% for choice in form_col.columns %}
    <td>{{ form_col.lol }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

Where form_col.lol is ChoiceField in forms.py, but then i couldn't get all choices:

```
print(form.cleaned_data['lol'])
```

This show only select in last ChoiceField.

Comment: try {{ choice.p }} perhaps. why not just make a form, then render the form?

Comment: post a sample output

Comment: Ok, i added it.

Comment: Are you looking for something more in line with? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242290/how-do-i-iterate-over-django-choices-in-a-template-without-using-a-form-or-mod](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242290/how-do-i-iterate-over-django-choices-in-a-template-without-using-a-form-or-mod)

Comment: I want to have ChoiceField in each columns and i don't know how many columns would be until I call set_columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yay, i think i found it.

First of all in form.py i deleted variable columns. I had to add new forms to fields wchich is a array in forms.Form. Also i had to create own render(?) function as_row:

```
class ChooseColumnsForm(forms.Form):
    choices = (
        (1, ("")),
        (2, ("sn")),
        (3, ("cn")),
        (4, ("password")),
        (5, ("uid")),
        (4, ("mail"))
    )
    def set_columns(self, col):
        for i in range(0,col):
            self.fields['column'+str(i)] = forms.ChoiceField(self.choices)
    def as_row(self):
        return self._html_output(
            normal_row='<td>%(errors)s%(field)s%(help_text)s</td>',
            error_row='<td colspan="2">%s</td>',
            row_ender='</td>',
            help_text_html='<br /><span class="helptext">%s</span>',
            errors_on_separate_row=False)
```

In views.py i am sending this

```
form_col = ChooseColumnsForm()
form_col.set_columns(length)
return render(request, 'django_ldap/add_students.html', {'form': form, 'form_col': form_col.as_row(), 'file2': file2})
```

And in html just

```
<thead>
    {{ form_col }}
</thead>
```