# Django loop through model choices

Tags: python, django, django-models

This is the base code I am using:

https://github.com/justdjango/video-membership/tree/master/courses

3 main files:

1. models.py
2. views.py
3. templates/course_list.html

But I added some more functionality to models.py to include a skill_level and subject with model choices:

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    SUBJECT_CHOICES = (
        ('tech', 'Technical'),
        ('bus', 'Business'),
        ('lead', 'Leadership'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=SUBJECT_CHOICES, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Skill_level(models.Model):
    SKILL_LEVEL_CHOICES = (
        ('Begin', 'Beginner'),
        ('Interm', 'Intermediate'),
        ('Adv', 'Advanced'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=SKILL_LEVEL_CHOICES, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Course(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField()
    allowed_memberships = models.ManyToManyField(Membership)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    subjects = models.ManyToManyField(Subject)
    skill_level = models.ManyToManyField(Skill_level)
    visited_times = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('courses:detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    @property
    def lessons(self):
        return self.lesson_set.all().order_by('position')
```

What I want to eventually do is to loop through the subjects and skill_levels so that the loop results could be used in a dropdown menu so users could search/filter for courses of a certain subject or courses of a certain skill level. But for right now I want to get the dropdown form populated with the choices.

Example Outcome:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAVjz.jpg

I would appreciate if someone could provide some code that could accomplish this.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service, please tell us what had you tried and please only show code in the post not from images

Comment: @LinhNguyen Ok sorry about that I tried following this similar question here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242290/how-do-i-iterate-over-django-choices-in-a-template-without-using-a-form-or-mod but I did not have any luck trying to get it to work with my code. Can you assist?

Comment: Hi minorees welcome to stackoverflow, please dont post code on pastebin-like services. do put your code in the question, we can guide you how once you have tried to resolve the issue yourself and got stuck. please read stackoverflow guideline on [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @BagusTesa ok thanks I edited the question to include the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Skill_level(models.Model):
    choices = models.CharField(max_length=25)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choices

class Course(models.Model):
    skill_level = models.ForeignKey(Skill_level, on_delete= ....)
```

You can try this way, it will show as drop down in your form.

Comment: sorry but not sure how to implement that. Right now I don't want to use a form I just want to list out the choices like the image shows.